# How to find values and slicing a list?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have the following list:

```
lst = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
      'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

I need to output this:

```
['December', 'January', 'February']
```

My code is:

```
print(lst[11:])
```

But right now I'm outputting this:

```
['December']
['January', 'February']
```

How do I output `['December', 'January', 'February']` in Python?

Comment: `print(lst[11:] + lst[:2])`?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you want to assume array as circular and want next 3 values after an index?

Comment: ```print(lst[-1:] + lst[:2])``` this could be easy solution.

Comment: `[lst[idx % len(lst)]for idx in range(len(lst)-1, len(lst) + 2, 1)]`